# If an integral is increasing, is the integrand non-negative?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a measurable, integrable function. Suppose that the function $$x\mapsto\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$$ is non-decreasing throughout $\mathbb R$.

Does it necessarily follow that $f$ is non-negative almost everywhere (with respect to the Lebesgue measure)?

I tried assuming the contrary (that is, that the set $\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,f(x)<0\}$ has positive Lebesgue measure) and using approximation arguments, but I seem to be stuck. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Regularity of Lebesgue measure might be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Notice that the function $x \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt $ is absolutely continuous, so you may apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to conclude its derivate is equal to $f$ a.e..

Comment: Thank you, you approach does work, indeed. However, I need this result precisely to prove a refined version of the fundamental theorem and I wanted to avoid a circular argument; hence the more complicated proof I came up with below. Again, I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is true. I will use the following two lemmas (displayed without proof). In what follows, let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure.

**Lemma 1** Given that $f$ is integrable, there exists, for each $\varepsilon>0$, some $\delta>0$ such that $\lambda(B)<\delta$ implies that $$\int_B|f(t)|\,\mathrm dt<\varepsilon$$ for any Borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb R$.

**Lemma 2** For any Borel set $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ and $\delta>0$, there exists a finite or countable *disjoint* (!) sequence of bounded intervals $C_1,C_2,\ldots$ such that $A\subseteq\bigcup_{\ell}C_{\ell}$ and $\lambda(\bigcup_{\ell} C_{\ell}\setminus A)<\delta$.

Now, if it were to be the case that $\lambda(\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,f(x)<0\})>0$, then it is not difficult to show that $\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,f(x)<-1/n\}$ would also have positive Lebesgue measure for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Let the latter set be denoted as $A$. Therefore, $\lambda(A)>0$, so that $\lambda(A)>\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.

By Lemma 1, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\lambda(B)<\delta$ implies that $$\int_B|f(t)|\,\mathrm dt<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$$ for any Borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb R$. For this $\delta>0$, consider a disjoint sequence of intervals $C_1,C_2,\ldots$ satisfying $A\subseteq\bigcup_{\ell}C_{\ell}$ and $\lambda(\bigcup_{\ell} C_{\ell}\setminus A)<\delta$, whose existence follows from Lemma 2. The latter condition implies that $$\int_{\bigcup_{\ell} C_{\ell}\setminus A}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\leq\left|\int_{\bigcup_{\ell} C_{\ell}\setminus A}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\right|\leq \int_{\bigcup_{\ell} C_{\ell}\setminus A}|f(t)|\,\mathrm dt<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}.$$

On the one hand, one has that $$\int_{\bigcup_{\ell} C_{\ell}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\sum_{\ell}\int_{C_{\ell}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\geq0,\tag{*}$$ since, for example, if the lower and upper endpoints of $C_{\ell}$ are $a_{\ell}$ and $b_{\ell}$, respectively, then $$\int_{C_{\ell}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_{a_{\ell}}^{b_{\ell}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_{-\infty}^{b_{\ell}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt-\int_{-\infty}^{a_{\ell}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\geq0$$ by the assumption of monotonicity.

On the other hand, one also has that $$\int_{\bigcup_{\ell} C_{\ell}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_{\bigcup_{\ell} C_{\ell}\setminus A}f(t)\,\mathrm dt+\int_{A}f(t)\,\mathrm dt<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}-\int_{A}\frac{1}{n}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\varepsilon}{n}-\frac{\lambda(A)}{n}<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}-\frac{\varepsilon}{n}=0,$$ which contradicts (*).